# Code does not appear to print concatenated strings correctly

Tags: c, string

I have some code here where, given a .txt file whose contents is

```
find replace pre
pre
cpre
```

,I want to find every instance of "pre", and append "k" to it. ie the file should become "find replace kpre".

So I first set out to create a string that is the concatenation of k and pre
(assume k and pre are argv[1] and argv[3], respectively)

```
char appended[1024];
strcpy(appended, argv[1]);
strcat(appended, argv[3]);
printf("appended string is %s", appended); //prints kpre, which is good

char *replaced = replace(buf, argv[3], appended);

//*string is a line in  the file
char* replace(char *string, char *find, char *replace) {
    char *position; 
    char temp[1024];
    int find_length = strlen(find);
    int index = 0;

    while ((position = strstr(string, find)) != NULL) {
        strcpy(temp, string);
        index = position - string;
        string[index] = '\0';
        strcat(string, replace); //add new word to the string
        strcat(string, temp + index + find_length); //add the unsearched 
              //remainder of the string
    }
   return string;
}

.................

fputs(replaced, temp);
```

Checking on the console, appended = "kpre", which is correct, but when the code is run the file looks like

```
find replace kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk.....kkkkkkk
kkkkkkkkk......kkkkk
ckkkkk....kkkkk
```

the k's go on for a while, I cannot see pre when scrolling all the way to the right. I'm having difficulty figuring out why the code doesn't replace
the instance of 'pre' with 'kpre', even when the appended variable appears to be correct. I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that I set a 1024 character for temp, but even then I'm not sure why k was copied so many times.

Comment: Here's a string `"pre"`, replace all instances of `"pre"` with `"kpre"`. Ok. That give me "kpre". Now, starting from the beginning of the string, repeat that. Um... if you start searching for `"pre"` from the beginning of the string you're going to find one for sure, because *you just wrote one*. So, the next result would be `"kkpre"`, then `"kkkpre`", then `"kkkkpre"` etc. . See the problem? You have to move where you search from to *not* include the text you just replaced. A *pointer* would really be ideal for that, btw.

Comment: I thought the line index = position - string  would update the index to the point where it is already past the portion of the string that has already been searched?

Comment: How would your search function (`strstr`) know that this "index" variable exists, much less what its value is?

Comment: What happens if `replace` is longer than `find` and `find` isn't the last word in `string`?

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
    while ((position = strstr(string, find)) != NULL) {
```

you are passing `string` to `strstr()` function. The `strstr()` will return the pointer to the first occurrence of `find` in `string`. When you replace `pre` with `kpre` and calling again `strstr()`, it is retuning the pointer to the first occurrence of `pre` in `string` which is a sub string of `replace` string. After some iterations of `while` loop, it will start accessing the `string` beyond its size which will lead to undefined behavior.

Instead of passing `string` to `strstr()`, you should pass pointer to `string` and after every replace operation, the make the pointer point to after the replaced part of string. Other way is you can traverse the string character by character using pointer instead of using `strstr()`, like this:

```
#define BUFSZ 1024

char* replace(char *string, const char *find, const char *replace) {
        if ((string == NULL) || (find == NULL) || (replace == NULL)) {
                printf ("Invalid argument..\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        char temp[BUFSZ];
        char *ptr = string;
        size_t find_len = strlen(find);
        size_t repl_len = strlen(replace);

        while (ptr[0]) {
                if (strncmp (ptr, find, find_len)) {
                        ptr++;
                        continue;
                }

                strcpy (temp, ptr + find_len);  // No need to copy whole string to temp
                snprintf (ptr, BUFSZ - (ptr - string), "%s%s", replace, temp);
                ptr = ptr + repl_len;
        }
        return string;
}
```

Note that above code is based on the example you have posted in your question and just to give you an idea about how you can achieve your goal without using `strstr()`. When writing code, take care of the other possibilities as well like, `replace` is a huge string.